# AsyncTasks and Audio

Tags: android, audio, android-asynctask

I am trying to play multiple audio files, one after the other and am currently using AsyncTasks to prepare and start the mediaPlayer but have failed to find a good way to move on the to next track at the end of the current one. Not every audio file will be played every time, and it's playing is decided by a boolean value.

Any help is much apprecieated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have read android-sdk/docs/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html , it says:

> When the playback reaches the end of stream, the playback completes.
>   If the looping mode was being set to truewith setLooping(boolean), the
>   MediaPlayer object shall remain in the Started state. If the looping
>   mode was set to false , the player engine calls a user supplied
>   callback method, OnCompletion.onCompletion(), if a
>   OnCompletionListener is registered beforehand via
>   setOnCompletionListener(OnCompletionListener). The invoke of the
>   callback signals that the object is now in the PlaybackCompleted
>   state. While in the PlaybackCompleted state, calling start() can
>   restart the playback from the beginning of the audio/video source.

So you may set a new source, prepareAsync then start in completion callback. In this way , you get continuous playback, but it is not seamless.

Comment: Thanks, that is a great way to use the same mediaPlayer to play all the tracks

Answer (score 0):

Doubtful using MediaPlayer for this will work like you want it to.  Try this tutorial:

http://www.droidnova.com/creating-sound-effects-in-android-part-1,570.html

If that doesn't work you'll probably have to mix the sounds together yourself them stream that result directly to the hardware using AudioTrack.  That's more low level, but it will give you the most control.  It just depends on what you are doing if the AudioManager solution will work for you or not.  It's definitely the simpler route.  But, if you're trying to line up two samples so that when one finishes the next begins, like in a music app, you probably will have to mix and stream that audio yourself.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html

[Algorithm to mix sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376036/algorithm-to-mix-sound)