# Float values read from ByteArray seem erroneous/irrational

Tags: floating-point, precision, actionscript

**Context:**
The application I am developing in AS3 requires an audio library that can mix multiple audio files together into one, apply fades, cut the audio short, loop it and pad it with empty noise. After doing a day's research I couldn't find any suitable libraries in AS3 that could do this so I started developing my own.

The library functions by working directly with the floating point values of the waveform, that is I convert an MP3 to a waveform using `Sound.extract()`. Any extractions are done in small chunks to avoid excessive memory usage. Most of the functionality of the library works fine (clip, fade, cut, loop, pad), minus the mixing process.

**The Problem:**
The mix function takes any number of sources (ByteArray holding a sequence of 32-bit floats), reads all the floats, adds them together and writes the result to an output, which is then clipped if it is out of range (1.0, -1.0) as detailed in this post: [Algorithm to mix sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376036/algorithm-to-mix-sound)

Here is the mix function:

```
public function mix(sources:Vector.<ByteArray>):ByteArray
{           
    var mixedBA:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    var expectedLengthInBytes:uint = sources[0].length;
    var floats:Vector.<Number>;
    var floatSum:Number;

    for each (var byteArray:ByteArray in sources)
    {
        byteArray.position = 0;

        if (byteArray.length != expectedLengthInBytes)
        {
            throw new Error("Parameter sources are not all the same length (bytes)!");
        }
    }

    var floatCount:uint = expectedLengthInBytes / FLOAT_SIZE_IN_BYTES;

    for (var i:uint = 0; i < floatCount; i++) 
    {
        floats = new Vector.<Number>();
        floatSum = 0;

        for each (var source:ByteArray in sources)
        {
            floats.push(source.readFloat());
        }

        for each (var float:Number in floats)
        {
            floatSum += float;
        }

        mixedBA.writeFloat(floatSum);
    }

    var clippedBA:ByteArray = clip(mixedBA);

    return clippedBA;
}
```

This works fine for only a few sources, but when you start to mix a lot of sounds together the `ByteArray.readFloat()` function seems to start return erroneous float values, well outside the range, anything from -7000.00000 to 1.123712832131E28 (which AS3 then seems to interpret as 1123712832131) to 56869.0000 (you get the idea).

**The Question:**
According to the Adobe docs `ByteArray.readFloat()` returns a 32-bit float but stores it in a Number for the return, which represents a 64-bit float. Additionally `ByteArray.writeFloat()` also writes a 32-bit float, but again takes a Number which represents a 64-bit float.

Is this conversion of precision what could be producing these extreme values? Or am I looking in the wrong place and there is actually an error in `Sound.extract()` (seems unlikely as I mentioned mixing only a few sounds together works fine)?

Comment: Try print out the hexadecimal values of the bytes, both before and after the "mixing". (If you would still like to keep the question here, please include this information into the question.) Also please read about the IEEE floating point representation. As for numerical operations, the input values must be in the correct type for the result of the operation to make sense. The question in its current form is unanswerable without knowing the binary representation (hex values). The incorrect floating point values only indicate a problem but do not help one solve it.

Comment: Where do the byte arrays come from? Is it possible you have a big/little endian problem?