# Android synthesis two tone(or more) to one?

Tags: android, sound-synthesis

How to synthesis two tone (or more) to one tone and play?

I found playing an arbitrary tone with Android in [Playing an arbitrary tone with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413426/playing-an-arbitrary-tone-with-android]).

Anyone has relevant information?

Comment: did you saw this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376036/algorithm-to-mix-sound